# How do I ignore entries based on boolean fields using default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

Simple question. Currently, for `Post` model, this is my setup for the default scope

```
default_scope :order => 'posts.created_at ASC'
```

How can I augment this to only have those where `:draft => false`

Also, how can I make a non-default scope to return those where `:draft => true`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use default_scope in this case. Use these regular scopes:

```
scope :drafts, where(:draft => true)
scope :published, where(:draft => false)
```

If you really want to use `default_scope` (which I don't recommend as it limits you and makes you have to get around it later), you can do it like this:

```
default_scope order('posts.created_at').where(:draft => false)
```

and to get drafts later:

```
@drafts = Post.unscoped.where(:draft => true)
```

But again, if you're using `default_scope` it means that you want it to ALWAYS use those conditions, and by using `unscoped` you're basically telling ActiveRecord NOT to do something that you explicitly told it to. To me, this is a hack.

Comment: +1.. avoid using the `default_scope` unless you know you *really* need it.

Comment: beaten on time, anyway I'd like to add that `where draft: true` can also be written `scoped_by_draft true`. All the best!